# qt programing help

Tags: qt4

i have an application which has rectangle pad on top of it i am displaying 3X4 grid of rectangle icons. i have selection rectangle which navigates in x and y axis when key is pressed. now my question is consider for example i am in fisrt icon( at pos(0,0)) i move to next icon when i do this i need to zoom that icon. is there a way to do so.....

i am working on linux(xubuntu)
and target is directfb(which supports only keyboard events)

please help

thanks

regards
rashmi

Answer (score 2):

Try using QGraphicsView for whole "grid thing". You can easily transform any element of QGraphicsView